# Why were the Unicode characters removed from this question?

Tags: discussion

I answered [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/377934/are-the-confirm-and-cancel-buttons-swapped-on-japanese-ps5) [ps5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps5) question that originally made use of Unicode characters in the title and the post (⭕ and ╳).  In the [edit history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/377934/revisions), I can see that the original poster wrote the question with these Unicode characters, but a Moderator edited the post to remove them.  The original poster then put the Unicode characters back in revision 5, to which a Moderator rolled back to Revision 4, removing them once again.

[image: History]

Is there any reason to remove the Unicode characters?  They seem valid given the context.  Is there a stance on Unicode characters like this and their use within posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unicode characters in question are the following:

```
U+2B55 : HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE {basic symbol for speed limit}
U+2573 : BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL CROSS
```

I can see a good argument here that these are simply not the correct characters for this purpose, even though they bear some resemblance to the controller buttons. But those characters certainly don't mean the same thing.

Unusual unicode characters also have a significant chance of simply not working in some settings. So there is a real drawback to using them.

If there were characters that actually represented the controller buttons I think it would make sense to use them. But using unrelated characters that resemble the buttons a bit is confusing at best, and mit actually just lead to empty boxes for some people when those characters are not available.

Comment: The points you make all seem good. Never heard anyone call the X button on a dualshock the "box drawings light diagonal cross" button before...  I would think though that most devices/browsers should be able to support these characters. That being said, I have seen those squares (□ character?) show up in other places across the web.

Comment: sony has a press kit you can leverage for the controller icons.